# Is there a way to append a count of objects in a nested collection as an attribute in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel, and specially eloquent. I have a Match model and this match has goals

```
class Match extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function goals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Goal::class, 'match');
    }

}
```

And I'm calling it from Controller like this:

```
public function matchesWithGoals()
    {
        $matches = Match::with('goals')->get();
        return compact('matches');
    }
```

This is returning each match with a collection of its own goals. All good so far.

```
{
"matches": [
{
"id": 13,
"date": "2022-01-05",
"goals": [
   {
      "id": 2,
      "player": 4,
      "match": 13,
      "team": "b"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "player": 13,
      "match": 13,
      "team": "b"
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "player": 4,
      "match": 13,
      "team": "a"
   }]
}]}
```

What I want to do, is take each nested collection of goals, add up based on the team, and append custom attributes "goalsTeamA", "goalsTeamB", "matchResult".

I tried to do this separate like, get all matches, get all goals, and join them. But it does seems like there should be a straight forward way to count elements inside the nested collection based on an attribute, in this case team, and append attributes so the intended result would be something like this:

```
{
"matches": [
   {
      "id": 13,
      "date": "2022-01-05"
      "goalsTeamA": 1,
      "goalsTeamB": 2,
      "Result": "b"
   }, 
   {
      "id": 14,
      "date": "2022-01-12"
      "goalsTeamA": 3,
      "goalsTeamB": 7,
      "Result": "b"
   }]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

BTW, the reason I'm trying to do it this way instead of just adding this columns to the DB with the scores is because I'm not just only be displaying scores counting up. Matches have other relationships like roster, and my goal is to learn how to process those nested relationship collections and append those results as attributes. Summing up the golas seemed like the most basic scenario.

Comment: Your proposed structure doesn't really work, unless I'm misunderstanding how the goals are stored. Aren't there more than 2 teams in the database? Naming the property after the team is not going to be a good solution as you'll need to know the name of the teams involved to get the data.

Comment: @miken32 you are correct. I should have that normalized into a teams table, but in this very particular case, it is only 2 teams, so I just have an enum "c" or "b" field as there are no more options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, so I will provide one possible solution.

You can look into Laravel Accessors - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

In your case, you could have functions on your Match model like so:

```
public function getGoalsTeamAAttribute() {
    // calculate and return goal count for team A
}

public function getGoalsTeamBAttribute() {
    // calculate and return goal count for team B
}

public function getResultAttribute() {
    // calculate and return result
}
```

You can then do one of two things to include this data on the collection.

1. Add `$appends = ['result', 'goals_team_a', 'goals_team_b'];` to the top of your Match model. This will append these values onto the collection when you cast it to an array or to JSON. Google 'laravel appends' for more info.
2. When you have a Match as an eloquent object, simply call `$match->goals_team_a` and it will do the calculation on the fly. You would want to be careful of n+1 problems with this approach, since it will run any database queries that are in your `getGoalsTeamAAttribute` function. You would want to make sure you're lazy loading (`->with('goals')`) before running `$match->goals_team_a`.

Comment: It does help! I did that and the custom params are there thank you!. I have my accessors now and my functions to set those accessors, currently returning 0, which gets me to the second part of the question, how can I count items in those nested collections to return the correct count?


Right now it looks like I should query the DB using query builder and the match ID, sort of separate from the already retrieved match with goals. In which case I don't know why I have the relationship. Maybe I don't need it

Comment: Nvm, indeed I didn't need the nested collection or the defined relationships. For my case using accessors and get values for those using Query Builder was enough.